# История изменений

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть коллекция, в которую пользователь может добавлять объекты и удалять их.

Подскажите каким образом можно реализовать функционал отмены/возврата изменений с помощью Ctrl+Z/Ctrl+Y?

Буду благодарен за любые наводки и ссылки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическим решением данной задачи, является применение паттерна [команда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Допустим, в методе `Execute()` будет код, который выполняет некоторое полезное действие, а в методе `Undo()` будет код, который отменяет это изменение (в вашем случае откат изменений коллекции). Вам необходим [стек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO) в который вы будете помещать такие объекты предварительно вызывая у них метод `Execute()` и соответственно, по Ctrl+Z вы будете разматывать такой стек, вызывая у операции, которую необходимо откатить, метод `Undo()`

```
public class Command
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Операция изменения коллекции
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        // Операция отката изменения
    }
}
```